# Getting error for SQL update query using java

Tags: java, sql

I am trying  to execute the below code to update a record with its length for  Txn_life_cycle_ID = MCC000100222333333

```js
ArrayList<String> update_TXN_LIFE_CYCLE_IDENTIFICATION = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    
    String Query_update_TXN_LIFE_CYCLE_IDENTIFICATION = "update t_clr_payment_cycle_header set TXN_LIFE_CYCLE_IDENTIFICATION = substr(TXN_LIFE_CYCLE_IDENTIFICATION,1,15) \r\n" + 
      " where payment_cycle_header_id= " + OnlineData.get(2) + ")";
    
    update_TXN_LIFE_CYCLE_IDENTIFICATION = DataBaseConnector.executeSQLQuery_List2("QA", Query_update_TXN_LIFE_CYCLE_IDENTIFICATION);
```

But i am getting below error can you please let me know what is causing this error . I am new to java appriciate if you can point out in simple way.
Please note that i am getting OnlineData.get(2) value from output of another select query

```
SQL Exception:[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@15834f2
```

Comment: you need to use parameters on your query

Comment: can you please elaborate or give a example

Comment: You don't handle the Exception correctly. Use ``printStackTrace()`` on the caught Exception to get a stacktrace that might give you more information.